# How to make it easier not to create a lot of conditions if elif

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
def add_plot(axs, type_, x, y, y1=None, y2=None, height=None):
    try:
        if type_ in ['plot', 'scatter', 'stem', 'step']:
            _plot, = axs.plot(x,y)
            # but if type_ == 'scatter', I wouldn't want to write a separate condition for each type_
            # would like something like
            _plot, = setattr(axs, type_, {'x':x,'y':y})
    except Exception as e: 
        print(str(e))
```

Help, can anyone know the solution, thanks in advance

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to achieve here ?  what outcome are you seeking ?

Comment: too late)) see answer from @jprebys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getattr`

```
plot = getattr(axs, type_)(x, y)
```